# Is there a way to expose a golang net/http application to my local network?

Tags: go, networking

I am currently working on an `golang / gin` API alongside a `React` front-end and I'm trying to check it out on my phone.

React naturally exposes the application on my local network as such:

```
You can now view dashboard in the browser.

  Local:            http://localhost:3000
  On Your Network:  http://xxx.xxx.x.xx:3000
```

But the `gin` API is only reachable from my local computer: It is not exposed on my local network.

Can this be achieved and how?

EDIT 1: I did search for answers on the web but wasn't successful

EDIT 2: Found the solution which wasn't related to network exposure but rather a typo on the front-end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Run the web server from the [http](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/) package with:

```
http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
```

If you must use gin, you can use the example from their home [page](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin#quick-start):

```
package main

import "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"

func main() {
    r := gin.Default()
    r.GET("/ping", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.JSON(200, gin.H{
            "message": "pong",
        })
    })
    r.Run() // listen and serve on 0.0.0.0:8080 (for windows "localhost:8080")
}
```

Comment: Maybe I wans't clear enough in my post for which I apologise. I am running the web server just fine on my `localhost` I am just unable to reach it on the network. Although by writting this comment I just found the answer to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Dumb mistake on my part:

On the front-end when I was contacting the API I was fetching `http://localhost:8080` instead of `http://xxx.xxx.x.xx:8080`.